# How to include html files in Adobe AIR?

Tags: html, templates, air, include, adobe

How to include common HTML template files like header, footer etc. in another html file in Adobe AIR?

Something similar to SSI:

```
<!--#include file="header.shtml"-->
```

or PHP:

```
include 'header.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:XML id="keyboard">
    <keyboard><![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.jQuery||document.write('<script type="text/'+'javascript" src="http:/'+'/ajax.googleapis.com'+'/ajax'+'/libs'+'/jquery'+'/1.8.0'+'/jquery.min.js"><'+'/script>');
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('h1').css('color','red');
                });
             </script>
             <style type="text/css">
                 h1{color:blue;}
             </style>
             <h1>html</h1>]]>
         </keyboard>
    </mx:XML>
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
        import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import mx.controls.HTML;

        [Bindable]
        private function insertHtml():void {
            browser.htmlLoader.window.document.write(keyboard.children());
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:HTML id="browser" location="http://www.w3.org" htmlDOMInitialize="insertHtml()" />
</mx:Application>
```

You also can load html from file.